# Why this SELECT of the recent added records doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, subquery

I was trying to SELECT records that were just inserted, but it doesn't seen to work.

Example:

```
create table tt_teste (id bigserial, descricao varchar);

with inseridos as (
  insert into tt_teste (descricao) values('Test 1') returning id
)
select *
from tt_teste
where id in (select id from inseridos);
```

I tried to rewrite in another way but the result is the same.

```
with inseridos as (
  insert into tt_teste (descricao) values('Test 2') returning id
)
select *
from inseridos i
  join tt_teste t on t.id = i.id;
```

The result is always empty. Even if I change the WHERE to "where 1=1 or id in (select id from inseridos)" the new records don't show up. They show up in the next run.

I am doing this because I want to SELECT and INSERT in another table with more data coming from a JOIN, but the database can't select the records just inserted. Seens some kind of concurrency issue.

Comment: you need to provide minimal-reproducible-example to help you better
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is expected and documented behaviour [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) "*All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables ... and means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query*"

Comment: @MoulitharanM I believe the example was minimal and reproducible. How do you suggest I improve it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you can answer using this comment. It exactly answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
with inseridos as (
  insert into tt_teste (descricao) values('Test 1') returning id
)
select *
from inseridos;
```

or if you want some other field you just inserted, then

```
with inseridos as (
  insert into tt_teste (descricao) values('Test 1') returning *
)
select *
from inseridos;
```

There shouldn't be much more to retrieve, unless you have some computed values, triggers filling some fields or some other automation which you didn't tell in your question.